# Attempt to construct a countable hamel basis for $\ell^p$, what elements does it miss in order to comply with Baire Category Theorem

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a collection of finite dimensional subspaces of $\ell^p$ indexed by the natural numbers.
The components of each $a\in \ell^p$ can likewise be indexed as $a_i$ for $i \in \Bbb{N}$

Now construct $X_n$ as follows:

For $e_i$ basis vectors in each $X_n$:

Let $X_1 = \text{span}(e_1,e_2,e_3)$

Let $X_2 = \text{span}(e_4,e_5,e_6)$

Let $X_3 = \text{span}(e_7,e_8,e_9)$

...

Let $X_n = \text{span}(e_n,e_{n+1},e_{n+2}), n \in 3\Bbb{N}+1$

Thus $X = \bigcup_{n\in 3\Bbb{N}+1} X_n$.

Yet since the interior of proper subspace of a normed vector space is empty, thus by Baire Category Theorem $X \subset \ell^p$, therefore what do the missing elements in $\ell^p - X$ look like?

Comment: Each element of $X$ is supported on only three coordinates. Perhaps you want to take the linear span of the union? Even then, you're only taking finite linear combinations, and you'll miss vectors supported on an infinite set.

Comment: I don't understand. Let the vector be $v=(1,2,4,1,2,4,1,2,4,...)$ then each $X_n$ will generate a vector (1,2,4,rest are zeros), thus the countable union of all $X_n$ will give $v$?

Comment: Only if you add them. Taking a union doesn't do that.

Comment: Ah I see, $\sum_{n\in 3\Bbb{N}+1}X_n$ no longer fullfill the requirement of a hamel basis because the linear combination is countable

Comment: Take a sequence of finite sets of rational numbers whose union is exactly Q. What is missing from the union in order to be the real numbers?

Comment: the missing set is the set of irrationals. But this example does not reflect well the scenario in the OP where the whole vector space is countably infinite not uncountably infinite like the reals, so I guess the answer might be as what David said, especially sequence space is over the reals or complex